# diff between path and data_path in sunspot.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot-rails

I have been trying to configure my Sunspot Solr for my environment. I am getting confused between `path` and `data_path`, Can any one give me the difference and how to use them.

I have been referring this,
https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/production
    data_path: /some_path
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    #path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

Comment: check http://sunspot.github.io/docs/Sunspot/Rails/Configuration.html

Comment: data_path : https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb#L247 Path: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb#L136

Comment: path: The url path to the Solr servlet (useful if you are running multicore).
      # Default '/solr/default'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Path: The url path to the Solr servlet (useful if you are running multicore).
      # Default '/solr/default'.   
Data Path: the path to store lucene index data files.
           #Default '#{Rails.root}/solr/data'
```

[data_path :](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb#L247)

[Path:](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb#L136)